# How to avoid catching IOException?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the AsyncTask with the following `doInBackground` method. This is supposed to read and write a stream. The problem is when the connection is disconnected IOException is being called before the `buffer` is empty (it leaves `while` loop before `len != -1`) and I would like to avoid that.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... StringUrls) {

    try {

   // ...

 len = in.read(buffer);

        while (len != -1) {

            bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            len = in.read(buffer);

            if (Recorder.this.isCancelled)  {

            Recorder.this.stopSelf();
                break;
            }

        }


        bufOutstream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());

        // 
    }


   return true;
}
```

Comment: I hope this is not the real code because there are some pitfalls

Comment: change try { } catch location, ie. put it inside while()

Comment: You want to make sure that you do not lose connection before your buffer gets empty ? I assume losing connection is not under your control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to exit the while loop, you need to move the try catch block inside the while loop. I would recommend to exit the loop with an exception, though. This is the code I would use:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... StringUrls) {
    Boolean success = true;
    len = 0;

    try {
        while (len != -1) {
            bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            len = in.read(buffer);

            if (Recorder.this.isCancelled)  {

            Recorder.this.stopSelf();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // do something with the exception and if you can't handle it here 
            // rethrow it!
            success = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            bufOutstream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do something with the exception and if you can't handle it here 
            // rethrow it!
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the exception is thrown, len holds the value of the *previous* read iteration, the last time it suceeded.

Anyways, I suggest:

```
    try
    {
        while ( (len = in.read()) > -1 )
        {

            bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);

            if (Recorder.this.isCancelled)  
            {

                Recorder.this.stopSelf();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( in != null )
        {
            try
            {
                in.close();
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                // And I don't caaare
            }
        }

        if ( bufOutstream != null )
        {
            try
            {
                bufOutstream.close()
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                // And I don't caaare
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can check the condition in your while loop:
`if` you find that the exception is thrown even when `len != -1` has not gone false,
then swallow the IOException, `else` you can throw it exclusively.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... StringUrls) {

        try {
            //...
            int  len = in.read(buffer);

            while (len != -1) {
                try{
                bufOutstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                len = in.read(buffer);

                if (Recorder.this.isCancelled)  {
                Recorder.this.stopSelf();
                    break;
                }
                }catch(IOException ioe){
                    if(len == -1){
                        throw new IOException(ioe);
                    }
                        /*IOException gets swallowed in case len != -1 is not met*/
                }
            }
            bufOutstream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            // ...
        }
    }
```